# Prepared statements while fetching prepared statement

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to make a loop with one INSERT query for each fetched row from a previous query with prepared statements. In a more visual way:

**MAKE QUERY**
  *While Fetching*
    - Make new query

I can't close my statement since I need it to keep working...
The problem is that when we use prepared statements, we have to fetch all data before doing a new prepare(). So, how could I do this? Maybe without statements, but it's not a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to kill your DB (and if you have a DBA your DBA is going to kill you) if you try to do this. The problem is that what you want to do is send one inser request per line to the database. You have to create and dispose of all these commands over and over again for each line of data. That is *expensive*.

If you are hard-set on doing it, Nothing prevents you from creating a second prepared statement (with a different name of course) within a loop which reads from the first, but I highly advise against it. At the very least, buffer your incoming data and insert a few hundred rows at a time.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The real situation is this: A user pastes a text, this text is splited up in phrases, then all those phrases are fixed up by other ones. After all of them are fixed up (may take some days) I want to move them to another table, for final purposes. The only way I know is getting and reinsering.

Comment: So then is your problem knowing whether or not the phrase has been fixed, and you want to do that by doing a comparison from one table to the other?

Comment: Mmmm... the problem is that I don't want the final table to be filled up with weird stuff. This way I make sure only reviewed and well formed data comes into the final table. So... table 1 is like a temp box where all data comes in before the final one, like a queue.

Comment: Why not insert the data directly into the final table after it has been edited ? If you want to review the edited data a final time then why not create an intermediary table. Assign each phrase an ID and then you can use JOINs to select a single (or many) phrases and their versions from the first and second tables before inserting into the final one.

Comment: It is going to be a nice solution. Thank you! :)