# mysql prepared statement in query while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a mysql query within each iteration of a while loop of the returning query. It works if I am using normal query function (mysqli_query). However, if I run it as a prepared statement, it does not work anymore. I am not sure where the problem is.

Here is the working code:

```
function pagGenerateResult(){

    $pgSql = "SELECT * from table1 ;"
    $result = $conn->query($pgSql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
            $var1=$row["r1"] ;
            $var2=$row["r2"] ;
            $var3=$row["r3"] ;
            $var3=$row["r3"] ;

           $insertSql= " UPDATE pg_rd SET num1='$var1' ,num2='$var2',num3='$var3' WHERE num4='$var4' ";

        mysqli_query($conn,$insertSql);
        }
    } else {
        echo "MySQL Error: 0 result ";
    }
    $result->free();
    $conn->close();
    die();
}
```

And if I change the logic within the while loop into prepared statement as the following , it stopped working.

```
function pagGenerateResult(){

    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    $pgSql = "SELECT * from table1 ;"
    $result = $conn->query($pgSql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
            $var1=$row["r1"] ;
            $var2=$row["r2"] ;
            $var3=$row["r3"] ;
            $var3=$row["r3"] ;

            $insertSql= " UPDATE pg_rd SET num1=? ,num2=?,num3=? WHERE num4=? ";
            //prepared statement 
            $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$insertSql)){
              echo "SQL prepared statement error";
            }
            else{
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"fffi",$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }

        }
        // echo $recomSpace. " ". $numPgs. " ". $numSlot;
    } else {
        echo "MySQL Error: 0 result ";
    }
    $result->free();
    $conn->close();
    die();
}
```

Comment: why you are mixing oop way with procedural way. do one-of them in your second code.

Comment: #1: move your prepared statement outside the loop and just bind the specific variables in the loop. That's one of the benefits: You can reuse the statement.

Comment: See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: try this:- `function pagGenerateResult(){
    $conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    $pgSql = "SELECT * from table1 ;"
    $result = $conn->query($pgSql);
    
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  if($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE pg_rd SET num1=? ,num2=?,num3=? WHERE num4=? ")){
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    
    $var1=$row["r1"] ;
    $var2=$row["r2"] ;
    $var3=$row["r3"] ;
    $var3=$row["r3"] ;
    $stmt->bind_param("fffi",$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);
    $stmt->execute();
   }
    $result->free();
  }
    }
    $conn->close();
}`

Comment: This is a perfect situation for preparing a parameterised statement once and executing it with new values many times

Comment: Also please define ___does not work anymore___ Exactly what does not work

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: **Obvious Error** You are not setting a `$var4` but you set `$var3` twice???

Comment: I do have a type -- should be $var4.

Comment: It seems that this is not going to work according to this ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103085/prepared-statements-while-fetching-prepared-statement

Comment: "mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$insertSql)" is where the error comes from . If I put "if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$insertSql){ xxxx}" in there, it will not go in the loop. And

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have double declaration of `$var3` (probably you've meant `$var4` and `r4`)

```
 $var1=$row["r1"] ;
 $var2=$row["r2"] ;
 $var3=$row["r3"] ;
 $var3=$row["r3"] ;
```

Second, instead of using loop in PHP you could use update-join

```
update pg_rd p
inner join table1 t on t.r4 = p.num4
set
  p.num1 = t.r1,
  p.num2 = t.r2,
  p.num3 = t.r3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. I chose procedural style mysqli so as to be consistent and easier to digest. I haven't tested the code fully. Hope it works fine already.

You didn't set **$var4**. Check the commented problem in the code.

```
function pagGenerateResult(){
    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
    $pgSql = "SELECT * from table1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $pgSql);

    if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
            $var1=$row["r1"] ;
            $var2=$row["r2"] ;
            $var3=$row["r3"] ;
            $var4=$row["r3"] ; // r3 or r4?

            $insertSql= " UPDATE pg_rd SET num1=? ,num2=?,num3=? WHERE num4=? ";
            //prepared statement 
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

            if( mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$insertSql) == FALSE ) {
              echo "SQL prepared statement error";
            }
            else{
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"fffi",$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else {
        echo "MySQL Error: 0 result ";
    }
    mysqli_close( $conn );
    die();
}
```